# Sharing Registry and Config Spaces across ESB cluster

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Having linked an instance of ESB v4.6.0 to a G-Reg v4.5.3 as per

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Remote+Registry+Instance+Configuration#RemoteRegistryInstanceConfiguration-Atom-BasedRemoteInstanceConfiguration

When the ESB starts it throws several errors like:

```
[Framework Event Dispatcher] ERROR AbstractTransportService Error while checking the transport availability 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Despite that, **I can browse** the Registry in both ends but when I create a BAM Profile in ESB while it's **successfully** saved in the Registry, the ESB starts to fail with:

```
[http-nio-9443-exec-37] ERROR RPCMessageReceiver Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getResourceString 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

and the BAM Profile can't be read in the ESB end neither through the Registry Browser (empty resource) nor the BAM Profile management page (Exceptions). But can be read in the Governance Registry browser.
I set the permissions wide open when I create the shared collection, and the artifacts can be read, write, etc. by everyone.

I can't find information about what can be wrong with the connection, to allow to browse and write, but prevents ESB to read.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll respond my own question, to help out somebody else facing the same issue.

Atom-based registry sharing is deprecated "de-facto" in newer versions of WSO2.

**Use JDBC-based registry sharing from now on.**

Regards

Answer (score 0):

i don't think its deprecated, im pretty sure its a bug, present in 4.5.1/2/3

[wso2esb wso2 governance registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421509/wso2esb-wso2-governance-registry/15425666?noredirect=1#15425666)

Comment: Hi Tim, according with WSO2 people, Atom is deprecated for this since causes many troubles. I don't know if it is going to be enabled again in the future. Regards.