# wso2esb wso2 governance registry

Tags: wso2-bam, wso2-esb

This seems like it's very basic functionality but doesn't work so well out of the box. Using ESB version 4.5.1 or 4.6.0, mount a registry version 4.5.0

Mount appears to work, structure is present, however the files are missing content.

This works with WSO2ESB 4.5.0 but the BAM doesn't work on that version so I am trying to get it working with 4.5.1

The same issue occurs in registry 4.5.1 and above when trying to mount using scm, directory structure is present but files are missing content.

Answer (score 0):

This content missing issue is due to bug in G-Reg 4.5.1.

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-1607

Thanks

Ajith